# camera movement trajectory three.js

Tags: three.js, camera, position

I think this picture better explains my problem: http://i48.tinypic.com/wvrbcy.png

On this picture the camera is moving along the ellipse. The code I have for this trajectory is:

```
var r = 0;
function render() {
    cameraMain.rotation.y+=0.003;
    cameraMain.position.x = Math.sin(r*0.1)*500;
    cameraMain.position.z = Math.cos(r*0.1)*1000;
    r+=Math.PI/180*2;
}
```

But that's not what I need. I want my camera to move in a kinda star trajectory, so that it'll have kinda 'zoom in' / 'zoom out' effect. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to google "parametric equation" for "astroid", or "deltoid curve", or "superellipse".

Here are some links where you can get the kinds of parametric equations you are looking for:

Astroid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid

Deltoid Curve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_curve